# Deriving standard normal distribution from a statistic involving normal and uniform random variables

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

[image: show that Z is standard normal]

I tried deriving distributions of numerator and denominator separately. But found that there is no closed form. I have no clue on how to show that Z is standard normal.

Comment: For homework/self-study type questions please add the self-study tag

Comment: This _must_ be a question in which the solver is expected to state which of the  the  four statements (marked 1 through 4 in the image) are true.  Statement 3 is clearly incompatible with Statements 1, 2 and 4. Statement 4 _is_ compatible with Statements 1 and 2 but need not be true in order for either 1 or 2 to be true.  **What exactly** is the question actually asked?  (Hint: this might be stated at the top of the page or at the beginning of the section.

Comment: Previously asked: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366806/sampling-distribution-using-normal-and-rectangular-distribution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider the conditional distribution $Z\mid( U_1=u_1,U_2=u_2)$ and use what you know about the reproductive property of univariate normal distribution. You would find that $Z\mid U_1,U_2$ is independent of $U_1,U_2$.